# How to create a new sheet in excel with powershell script

Tags: excel, powershell

My question is in the title, i dont know how to create a new sheet in excel using a powershell script.

here is my code :

```
#Define locations and delimiter
$csv = $pathcsv
$xlsx = $pathxlsx
$delimiter = "," #Specify the delimiter used in the file

# Create a new Excel workbook with one empty sheet
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

# Build the QueryTables.Add command and reformat the data
$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $csv)
$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
$query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)
$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $delimiter
$query.TextFileParseType  = 1
$query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,1 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
$query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

# Execute & delete the import query
$query.Refresh()
$query.Delete()

# Save & close the Workbook as XLSX.
$Workbook.SaveAs($xlsx,51)

$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($pathxlsx)

Add-Worksheet -ExcelPackage $excel -WorkSheetname "test"

$excel.Quit()
pause
```

So i try the commande Add-Worksheet -ExcelPackage $excel -WorkSheetname "test" but it seems not working, can you help me with that ?

I got the following error :

Add-Worksheet : Unable to process argument transformation on parameter "ExcelPackage". impossible to
convert the value "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass" to type "
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass "and type" OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage ".
Au caractère C:....\NEW.ps1:125 : 29

- Add-Worksheet -ExcelPackage $excel -WorkSheetname "NewSheet"
- ```
                          ~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData : (:) [Add-Worksheet], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Add-Worksheet

thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it seems not working" - does it throw an error? Nothing happening? Computer catching on fire? Please be mindful that only _you_ can see your screen :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append a new sheet to the opened Excel file as last sheet, you can do the following:

Remove the line `Add-Worksheet -ExcelPackage $excel -WorkSheetname "test"` and instead write:

```
# get the last sheet in the workbook
$lastSheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets($Workbook.WorkSheets.Count)
# create a new sheet and insert it before the last sheet
$newSheet = $workbook.WorkSheets.Add($lastSheet)
# give it a name
$newSheet.Name = 'test'
# now move the previous last sheet before the new sheet, so now THAT will become the last
$lastSheet.Move($newSheet)

# Save & close the Workbook as XLSX.
$workbook.SaveAs("D:\Test\test.xlsx",51)

$excel.Quit()
# don't forget to clear the COM objects from memory
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($lastSheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($newSheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```